# How to set frame rate with Android CameraX ImageAnalysis?

Tags: java, android, image, frame-rate, android-camerax

I would like to increase the FPS that image analysis is able to get. I logged it on the console and it tops at about 10 FPS. How can I get it to 30 FPS?

```
void bindPreview(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {

        final String TAG = "FPSCounter";
        final long[] startTime = {System.currentTimeMillis()};
        final int[] frameCount = {0};

        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime[0];
                double fps = (double) frameCount[0] / (elapsedTime / 1000.0);
                Log.d(TAG, "FPS: " + String.format("%.2f", fps));
                frameCount[0] = 0;
                startTime[0] = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .build();

        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), image -> {
            // This method will be called every time a new frame is available
            // You can use the 'image' object to get the current frame

            frameCount[0] = frameCount[0] + 1;

            image.close();
        });

        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();

        previewView = (PreviewView) findViewById(R.id.previewView);

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

        Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis);
    }
```

I have read that there is no consistent way in setting the FPS in CameraX Image Analysis but I am hoping someone would be able to help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late but for anyone struggling with this, I remember it was possible via Camera2Interop Extender. Can be set like this:

```
val ext = Camera2Interop.Extender(imageAnalysisConfig)
    ext.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO)
    ext.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, Range<Int>(30, 30))
```

where `imageAnalysisConfig` is:

```
val imageAnalysisConfig = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
        .setTargetResolution(Size(PREVIEW_HEIGHT, PREVIEW_WIDTH))
        .apply {
            setImageQueueDepth(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
        }
```